# manually installung Grub2 after Windows8.1 update 1

Tags: grub2, windows-8, uefi, grub-efi

After boot-repair failed to install (both with secure boot disabled and enabled), I decided to try running grub-install manually using the following command.

`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/root/ --efi-directory=/boot --uefi-secure-boot /dev/sda7`

Where `/dev/sda7` is the root for the Ubuntu install. however, this prints `Installing for i386-pc platform.`, and I'm on a 64 bit machine.  It fails, saying:

```
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.
grub install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I tried adding `--target=x86_64-efi`, but that prompted `grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.`

An `ls` showed that, indeed, this file didn't exist.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ ls /usr/lib/grub
grub-mkconfig_lib  i386-pc
```

I don't really know what to do now.  I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on a live USB.  The machine is a Toshiba Sattellite P55t with an i5.

Comment: can I retract this quiestion? I just reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package `grub-efi-amd64-bin` on your running live-system. 
You can do this by using the following command:

> sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-bin